# How to stop the "Lead: [full name] has been assigned to you" emails

Tags: apex, trigger, leads, assignment-rules

I'm assigning lead ownership via apex triggers (before insert, before update) and would like to not have it send out the "Lead: [full name] has been assigned to you" email to the new owner.  How do I stop those from going out?

Side note: I'm assigning via apex trigger because it's dependent on some other territory assignments that happen based on address during the before insert and before update triggers already, so I'm not interested in Lead Assignment Rules as a solution...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use the `DmlOptions.EmailHeader` Class for this.  The class has 3 properties that can send or suppress system emails.  The property you are looking for is `triggerUserEmail`.  Here is an example of how you would use it

```
 Database.DMLOptions options = new Database.DMLOptions();
 //THE PROPERTY YOU ARE LOOKING FOR
 options.EmailHeader.triggerUserEmail = false; 

 //ADDITIONAL PROPERTIES THAT MAY COME IN HANDY
 options.EmailHeader.triggerAutoResponseEmail = false;
 options.EmailHeader.triggerOtherEmail = false;

 database.update(Record_or_List of records, options);
```

Here is a link to the documentation

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_class_Database_EmailHeader.htm

***EDIT***

If you are working with beforte triggers, this will not work.  From the docs

> it only applies to DML calls made after the DML options are applied.
>   I.e. you would need to generate a list of objects to insert/update and
>   set DMLOptions on them.

Here is a knowledge article that gives the workaround of using future methods to make this work

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000176854&language=en_US

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that for me.  However, any way to suppress while in a before insert or before update trigger context?  Would I need to launch an @future to update these?

Comment: Ahhhh yes, I missed that part of your question where it stated these were before triggers.  Yes, a future method is the way to go.  I have updated the answer and added a knowledge article.

Comment: Thank you, sir.  I'll implement that shortly and let you know how it goes...

Comment: Oh man, I am now running into an issue where that @future is failing unit tests because i have a batch job that updates lead records (Future method cannot be called from a future or batch method).  Any ideas?